# How to properly open and close an already fopened gzip file with zlib?

Tags: c, valgrind, zlib, c99, msvcrt

I'm writing a small C library that reads gzip files passed as `FILE *`. I'm using zlib's `gzdopen()` to open the file file descriptor:

```c
int zOpenCloseTest(FILE *const plainFile) {
    gzFile file = gzdopen(fileno(plainFile), "rb");
    if(file == NULL) {
        goto error;
    }
    if(gzclose_r(file) != Z_OK) {
        goto error;
    }
    return 0;
    error:
    // gzdopen does not close fd if it fails
    fclose(plainFile);
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    FILE *const file = fopen("test.xp", "rb");
    if(file == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(zOpenCloseTest(file) < 0) {
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The [zlib manual](https://zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip#:%7E:text=File%20descriptors%20are%20obtained%20from%20calls%20like,they%20need%20to%20have%20different%20file%20descriptors.) states:

> File descriptors are obtained from calls like `open`, `dup`, `creat`, `pipe` or `fileno` (in the file has been previously opened with `fopen`). [...] The next call of `gzclose` on the returned `gzFile` will also close the file descriptor fd, just like `fclose(fdopen(fd), mode)` closes the file descriptor `fd`. If you want to keep `fd` open, use `fd = dup(fd_keep); gz = gzdopen(fd, mode);`. [...] **If you are using `fileno()` to get the file descriptor from a `FILE *`, then you will have to use `dup()` to avoid double-`close()`ing the file descriptor.** Both `gzclose()` and `fclose()` will close the associated file descriptor, so they need to have different file descriptors.

I don't want to keep the file opened, so I create no duplicates.

The mentioned code creates a `Leak_StillReachable` error on line 21 (fopen) when checked with Valgrind memcheck (`--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --vgdb=no --track-fds=yes`).
On windows, it crashes with a "Debug assertion failed!" `(_osfile(fh) & FOPEN) close.cpp line 49` error box.

[image: error image]

Both are built in "debug mode".

The library is part of a bigger CMake project, and the user can choose whether to build it as a static or shared library. In either case, I want zlib to be statically linked to the library.
I initially thought the crash was due to mismatching run-time library link modes between the library and zlib, but the minimal example shows it's not the case?
If you inspect the CMake output, you can see zlib is being built with `/MDd` flags, as should be.
(modern) CMake in general defaults to "MultiThreaded$<$CONFIG:Debug:Debug>DLL" for `CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY`.

I believe I forgot something important about how the file descriptor<->stream relation works.
The [code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/Lucide/cmake-hunter-test). The project uses Hunter to setup zlib automatically in a CMake-friendly way.
The source is cross platform, the mre provides definitions to quiet msvc warnings.

Comment: I guess the underlying problem is that `gzclose` closes the file descriptor but knows nothing about the stdio stream on top of it. It's similar to doing a `close(fileno(fp));` on a stdio stream. You could perhaps do something like: `fd = dup(fileno(plainFile));` `fclose(plainFile);` `file = gzdopen(fd);` `if (gzclose_r(file) != Z_OK) {` `close(fd);` `return -1;` `}`. MS CRT probably wants you to use `_dup` and `_close` instead!

Comment: The thing is that zlib man explicitly states "The next call of `gzclose` on the returned `gzFile` will **also** close the file descriptor `fd`, just like `fclose(fdopen(fd), mode)`."
`fclose` takes a `FILE*` and closes the whole thing, not just the descriptor. I've also highlighted the section where it looks like it's advising no not call `fclose` after `gzclose`.
Right about the mscrt warnings, I'll add a note.

Comment: Thanks!, you and Mark Adler made me realize I really needed to revise my knowledge about io. Before closing the question, I take the chance to ask why did you put a `close(fd)` inside `gzclose_r`'s error handling? Can a `gzclose` fail leave the descriptor open? That would let you handle both errors in one step because if `gzdopen` fails, it's guaranteed that `gzclose` will fail too?

Comment: It looks like `gzclose` always calls `close` on the file descriptor unless it returns `Z_STREAM_ERROR`. If the return value is `Z_ERRNO` then `close` returned an error,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing what the zlib documentation says to do, which you yourself highlighted in the question. Use `dup()`.